# how to use sum function with join in MySQL

Tags: mysql, join, sum

```
select sum(bales) as bales 
  from receive_bardana  
  join receive_wheat
    on receive_bardana.id = receive_wheat.id 
 where id=1
```

my result is showing wrong output

Comment: Please add schema of table with some sample data

Comment: Assuming bales is a numeric data type the query should work so you will need to prove that it does not by supplying  table definitions andsample data,

Comment: Output looks just fine to me

Comment: without join its showing correct value but with join its showing increased value

Comment: No it isn't. It looks exactly the same either way.

Answer (score 0):

Your query 1)should not even syntax given id is ambiguous in the where clause 2) the joined table is pointless since you don't use anything from it in the select 3) From the little information you have provided in the question there  is a 1 to many relationship between receive_bardana and receive_wheat which means that the sum is over all the joined rows for example

```
create table receive_bardana(id int,bales int);  
create table receive_wheat(id int);

insert into receive_bardana values (1,10),(2,20);  
insert into receive_wheat values(1),(1),(2),(2),(2);

select *
  from receive_bardana  
  join receive_wheat
    on receive_bardana.id = receive_wheat.id 
 where receive_bardana.id;
```

Result

```
+------+-------+------+
| id   | bales | id   |
+------+-------+------+
|    1 |    10 |    1 |
|    1 |    10 |    1 |
|    2 |    20 |    2 |
|    2 |    20 |    2 |
|    2 |    20 |    2 |
+------+-------+------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

and with your (fixed) query

```
select sum(bales) as bales 
  from receive_bardana  
  join receive_wheat
    on receive_bardana.id = receive_wheat.id 
 where receive_bardana.id;
```

the sum correctly returns

```
+-------+
| bales |
+-------+
|    80 |
+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Which explains fully the 'problem' you are having.
If you want a answer to what you are trying to do I suggest you raise a new question describing what you are trying to do rather than just saying this lump of code does not do as I expect (in fact it does what I expect and is not 'wrong')